# Using Ansible to install Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

Some time ago I asked a question regarding Ansible and Docker and received [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32105086/4009451). I am now trying to understand that answer a bit better. Essentially, I have a bunch of Ubuntu 14.04 VMs and I want Ansible to install/maintain Docker on all of them.

My Ansible project:

```
myansible01.example.com:/opt/ansible/
    site.yml
    allservers.yml
    roles/
        common/
            tasks/
                main.yml
```

Where `site.yml` is:

```
---
# file: site.yml
- include: allservers.yml
```

Where `allservers.yml` is:

```
---
# file: allservers.yml
- hosts: all
  user: {{ privileged_user }}
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - common
```

And where `roles/common/tasks/main.yml` is:

```
---
# file: roles/common/tasks/main.yml
- name: Add docker apt keys
  apt_key: keyserver=keyserver.ubuntu.com id=36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
- name: Update apt
  apt_repository: repo='deb https://get.docker.com docker main' state=present
- name: Install Docker
  apt: pkg=lxc-docker update_cache=yes
```

Finally, my `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
[allservers]
server01.example.com
server02.example.com
server03.example.com
...etc.
server49.example.com
server50.example.com
```

Several concerns here:

- How do I actually run this so that Ansible installs Docker on all 50 servers? Something like (from the project root) `ansible-playbook site.yml -f 10`?
- How do I "inject" the `privileged_user` into the above command?
- Why is the first task "*Add docker apt keys*" necessary? According to the [`apt_key` docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_key_module.html), we are fetching an `apt_key` from the Ubuntu repos, but where does that long key come from? What role does this play in installing Docker (I ask because if you go to the [Docker Ubuntu installation page](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installation) it doesn't mention these `apt_keys` at all)?
- Anything else I need to do for a proper Docker install?

Comment: >Anything else I need to do for a proper Docker install? - I would add the regular users to the Docker group so they won't have to use sudo with the docker commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a more logical order :

**Why `apt-key` ?**

`apt-key` is used to manage the list of keys used by `apt` to authenticate packages (like *docker*). Packages which have been authenticated using these keys will be considered trusted. It is useful when you add a repository where a newer / better / up-to-date release of a package you want resides.

*(source : man page of apt-key)*

If you don't add the key of the repo first, `apt` won't be able to get the package, and will cry with **"W: GPG error: ... The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY whatever key number"**. So this is basically so that you can get the package and install it.

In the [docker Ubuntu installation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installation) page, there is a clear mention of `apt-key` at point **3** in the note :

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Variables**

To inject `{{ privileged_user }}` in your config : you would use a global variable by defining `privileged_user` in `<INVENTORY_FILE_LOCATION>/group_vars/all` like that :

```
---
# Your user
privileged_user: "root"
```

*If this `group_vars/all` file does not exist, create it.*

> NB : the default inventory file location is `/etc/ansible/hosts`, but `/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts` on Mac OS X

*(see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) as well for more info)*

**Running a playbook**

Then, to run your playbook, do :

```
ansible-playbook -l server49.example.com allservers.yml -v
```

`-l` is if you want to limit to a server in particular for instance, but you can omit it

`-v` is if you want a verbose output (or `-vv`, `-vvv` ...)

**EDIT : Starting the docker daemon**

If you want to be sure that the docker daemon is started after that, I'd recommend restarting it anyway with :

```
- name: Start Docker
  service: name=docker state=restarted
```

Depending on the distributions, it may have been previously started automatically, but from what I understand in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/) here, *"Once Docker is installed, you will **need** to start the Docker daemon"*.

---

And .... you're good to go ;)

Comment: Thank you @tchap (+1) - Can you please also confirm that my `site.yml`, `allservers.yml` and that my `roles/common/tasks/main.yml` look correct (that is, they look correct **and** they don't look like they're missing anything important)? Thanks again!

Comment: I'd say that `site.yml` is a bit redundant since it only includes `allservers.yml`, but well. One thing you missed is updating `apt` by adding `update_cache: yes` in your `apt_repository` command. Then, depending on what you want to do with docker, you could set docker daemon options, start docker, install other packages like docker-compose, etc ... but it is really dependant on your use case

Comment: Thanks again @tchap (+1 again) - last followup, I promise! I was under the impression that my above/current setup would start running Docker engine for me. For example, if I manually install Docker on an Ubuntu VM, I can then issue `docker --version` and it will produce versionin output. If you are saying that *something else* needs to be executed in order to actually start the Docker daemon/engine (**BTW, is there a difference between those?**), can you please update your answer to show what it would take to subsequenly start it up? Thanks again!!!

Comment: That can or cannot be the case, it depends. I'd recommend restarting it anyway, it doesn't harm. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @tchap - bounty granted! Actually I can't award it for 22 hrs, so hang tight!

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate if you have any other questions